# How to add Python type hints to runtime type

Tags: python, type-hinting

How would you add type hints to this function?

```py
def cast_to(x, ty=bool):
    return ty(x)
```

Comment: Cannot be achieved in Python without Generics

Comment: Python has Generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm it seems you can do it like this:

```py
from typing import Type, TypeVar, Any

T = TypeVar('T')

def cast_to(x: Any, ty: Type[T] = bool) -> T:
    return ty(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic

```
X = TypeVar('X')

def cast_to(x, ty:Type[X] = bool) -> X:
    return ty(x)
```